# Android : Referencing child fragment from parent fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment

I have nested fragment scenario. Attempts to reference the child fragment from the parent fragment gives a null. What am I missing here?

This is the layout file of the parent fragment.

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Statically nested fragment -->
    <fragment
        android:name="reports.fragments.fragments.usageBreakUp.fragments.Filter"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_filter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is how I am trying to access the child fragment from the parent fragment

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "ON VIEW CREATED");

    filter = (Filter) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_filter);
    filter.populateStorageFilter(); // NPE here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this

```
filter = (Filter) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably get NPE inside `populateStorageFilter` because your child fragment's `onViewCreated` hasn't been called yet, i.e. child's view hasn't been initialized. So if you use any view references inside `populateStorageFilter`, they are `null`. You have to wait for child fragment's view to create and then call `populateStorageFilter`.